# Which statement clears the previous Graphics and draw a new One in Java?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

This is The Code :

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.fillOval(x, y, 25, 25);

    repaint();

}
```

This will create an output like This where if i move the pointer it doesn't clear the previous Graphics and creates a Path .

[Output of Above Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yJ5l.jpg)

And by adding the super statement like this it Doesn't show the Path but only the Current location of the Oval Graphic.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.fillOval(x, y, 25, 25);

    repaint();

}
```

[The output is This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jdopp.jpg)

I just want to the Mechanism and The Reason Behind This.

Comment: why not try to fill previous painted object color to background color.Hope this may help to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but there is so much wrong with your code, that we have to fix it:

- First off, don't override a JComponent's (or JFrame's) paint method but rather override the JComponent's or JPanel's paintComponent. This way you avoid mistakingly messing up painting of borders or child components, both of which paint is responsible for. Also since paintComponent has automatic double buffering, your animation will be much smoother.
- Next, you almost always do want to call the super's painting method, which for paintComponent is `super.paintComponent(g)` as this will continue to propagate the painting chain, whereas by not calling this you break this chain. Calling the super's method will call the component's housekeeping painting including the overpainting of "dirty" pixels which is why the trails are removed. This is likely the answer that you're looking for.
- Most important **never** call `repaint()` from within any painting method. Doing this results in a poor-man's animation that is completely uncontrollable, and puts too much responsibility on the painting method which should focus on its sole job -- to paint the component. Use a game loop such as a Swing Timer instead.

Most important -- read the tutorials as most of this is already explained there:

- [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html): introductory tutorial to Swing graphics
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html): advanced tutorial on Swing graphics

Comment: Can you explain why it happens and why it doesn't happen the 2nd time. And I'm new to this so can you please be a little less technical

Comment: @TusharSharma: already did that. The super's method cleans the "dirty" pixels -- see point 2 above.

Comment: Thank you so much :) now i know i can dive deeper

Answer (score 2):

Straight from the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#paint%28java.awt.Graphics%29)

> public void paint(Graphics g)
>
> Paints the container. This forwards the paint to any lightweight
> components that are children of this container. If this method is
> reimplemented, super.paint(g) should be called so that lightweight
> components are properly rendered. If a child component is entirely
> clipped by the current clipping setting in g, paint() will not be
> forwarded to that child.

As he said that super.paint() cleans the dirty pixels. This says it all .!! :)

Comment: But if we use double buffer without the super.paint(); it does the job too. Why?

Comment: In double buffering, instead of drawing your objects one by one, you draw them on an image and then tell the renderer to draw that entire image.